# find New Emails that comes into exchange email server

Tags: c#, sql, email, exchange-server

Right now I have a Microsoft Exchange mail server and I want to extract information from that exchange server directly to my own SQL database so I can analyze them.

Now the problem is right now the way I come up with extract information from this exchange database is to check every user then check every folder they have then check all the content under each folder and if I see any modified or new emails I copy,update that into my own database.

this method does work for small amount of data however if I try to copy large amount of data with this :eg 1000 users the process will take minutes if not longer because I am constantly doing loops over loops to check every single email one by one for difference. I want to have a way to only loop through a folder if it is modified.

I looked at the [documentation of Microsoft on Exchange folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder_properties(v=exchg.80).aspx) I see the function called IsDirty. The description says it returns true or false based on whether the object has been modified. Now I am confused on what is it comparing the object to. Does it compare the object with whether it was modified upon creation? or a specific date I tried to look for information on this and I can't find any. Also is there any other faster way of detecting new emails/modified emails in the exchange without looping through all the folders and all the emails thanks.

Comment: Ps I do not want to extract directly from exchange database I want to try to stick with the exchange SDK unless I absolutely have to use database access.

Comment: The exchange servers I work with are 2010 or later